# Getting this openai typescript error (Type 'MessageInterface' is not assignable to type 'ChatCompletionMessageParam')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openapi

I am getting this error on create method for typescript but could not able to resolve it.

`No overload matches this call. Type 'MessageInterface' is not assignable to type 'ChatCompletionMessageParam'.ts(2769)`

```
  interface MessageInterface {
    role: string;
    content: string;
  }


  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageInterface[]>([
    {
      role: "system",
      content: "You are a helpful assistant designed to output JSON.",
    },
  ]);

  const prompt: MessageInterface = { role: "user", content: input };

  setMessages([...messages, prompt]);
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [...messages, prompt],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
    response_format: { type: "json_object" },
  });
```

I assumed that messages are an array of objects. I also looked into the completion.ts but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the `ChatCompletionMessageParam` type in the [source code](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/c9bb4edaf5bc72ccd81fd7978abd468169255f1c/src/resources/chat/completions.ts#L445C13-L445C39), we’ll see that it is a union of a few interfaces:

```
type ChatCompletionMessageParam =
  | ChatCompletionSystemMessageParam
  | ChatCompletionUserMessageParam
  | ChatCompletionAssistantMessageParam
  | ChatCompletionToolMessageParam
  | ChatCompletionFunctionMessageParam;
```

The important part is that each of those interfaces doesn’t have property `role` with type `string` as you have defined in your `MessageInterface` interface. The `role` in each of them is a more precise type rather than just a generic `string`:

```
role: 'system' | 'user' | 'assistant' | 'tool' | 'function'
```

And `string` will never be assignable to any of those values above.

I suggest to change the type of the `role` in the `MessageInterface` to the one [defined by the library](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/blob/c9bb4edaf5bc72ccd81fd7978abd468169255f1c/src/resources/chat/completions.ts#L514C13-L514C31):

```
type ChatCompletionRole = 'system' | 'user' | 'assistant' | 'tool' | 'function’;
```

If you absolutely need to keep your own `MessageInterface` you can do:

```
interface MessageInterface {
  role: ChatCompletionRole;
  content: string;
}

// OR

interface MessageInterface {
  role: 'system' | 'user' | 'assistant' | 'tool' | 'function';
  content: string;
}
```

But it’ll be easier to just import existing `ChatCompletionMessageParam` type from the library and use it instead of `MessageInterface`.